# How to have multiple authors with one affiliation?

Tags: author

I am using the Springer Latex template that has the following header for authors:

```
\author{First Author\inst{1}\orcidID{0000-1111-2222-3333} \and
Second Author\inst{2,3}\orcidID{1111-2222-3333-4444} \and
Third Author\inst{3}\orcidID{2222--3333-4444-5555}}
%
\authorrunning{F. Author et al.}
% First names are abbreviated in the running head.
% If there are more than two authors, 'et al.' is used.
%
\institute{Princeton University, Princeton NJ 08544, USA \and
Springer Heidelberg, Tiergartenstr. 17, 69121 Heidelberg, Germany
\email{lncs@springer.com}\\
\url{http://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs} \and
ABC Institute, Rupert-Karls-University Heidelberg, Heidelberg, Germany\\
\email{\{abc,lncs\}@uni-heidelberg.de}}
```

According to the example it generates something like this:

[image]

In the article that I am making we have two authors with the same affiliation, but different emails, so I have done something like this:

```
\author{Professor X\inst{1} \and
Professor Y\inst{2} }
%

% First names are abbreviated in the running head.
% If there are more than two authors, 'et al.' is used.
%
\institute{My Institute \\
\email{profX@outlook.com, profY@gmail.com}\\
```

}

The problem that I have is that it shows something like:

```
Prof X_1 and Prof Y_2   //where 1 and 2 are overscripted
My Institute
emailX, emailY
```

, but I want to show it like:

```
Prof X1 and Prof Y2   //where 1 and 2 are overscripted
My Institute 1_2
emailX_1, emailY_2
```

How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like

```
\author{Professor X\inst{1} \and Professor Y\inst{2} }

\institute{  My Institute\inst{1,}\inst{2} \\
\email{profX@outlook.com, profY@gmail.com}}
```

[image]

However, the superscripts are usually used when the authors have different affiliation.